# Issue in couchbase srver opening

Tags: couchbase

I am using couchbase server , I have opened it and got popup as 
"IP address seems to have changed . Unable to listen on 'ns_1@10.0.2.15'"
and after that it is showing error like localhost refused connection.

how to resolve this problem?
and what is exact root cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Couchbase installation in a developer environment then this is probably a benign issue.

What the error message is telling you is that the IP address that it had previously identified itself as does not appear to be valid any longer (This could happen in a developer environment if your router has given you a new IP). Generally this is a bad thing for a production deployment as if it is part of a cluster then the other nodes will no longer be able to see it.

If it is a single node and nothing external is trying to reach it with a fixed IP then there is no need to worry and there are no issues to be resolved.